# Typeclass for my Pair a a

Tags: haskell

I got the following:

```
data Pair a =
  Pair a a
```

And want to instantiate the Eq typeclass to it.

```
instance Eq (Pair a) where
  (==) (Pair x x') = x == x'
```

I get the error:

*Couldn't match expected type Pair a -> Bool' with actual type Bool'*

What did I write wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your implementation doesn't work because

```
(==) :: a -> a -> Bool
```

You are assuming (==) takes one argument ((Pair x x') is actually one argument) and it actually needs two. Hence the error,

```
Couldn't match expected type Pair a -> Bool' with actual type Bool'
```

`(==)` was partially applied so it returned `Pair a -> Bool` while it was expected to return a Bool.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is the correct one but I am not 100% sure.

```
instance Eq a => Eq (Pair a) where
  (==) (Pair x x') (Pair y y') = x == y && x' == y'
```

Comment: That's correct: an `Eq T` instance provides a way to compare two values of type `T`. In your case, that's two pairs.